# Word for "a deep study"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, terminology, vocabulary

In the past few years I've started to do personal studies on different topics ranging all parts of life. They range in length from a week to a few months, on and off, but focus on understanding a particular subject more fully than I did at the start by reading, thinking, and writing about it.

I'm looking for a term (noun) to describe this or a verb to describe the act of doing the deep study on a particular topic. Are there any English words to properly describe this?

Comment: *Investigation*

Comment: To study something doesn't usually mean in a shallow way. Somebody studying at college/university will do so for years but wouldn't call it deep because that is normal.

Comment: I've taken courses in fields I was not familiar with to gain a better understanding.  They were called _surveys_.

Comment: Please don't use "in depth".  This phrase has been overused.  Maybe once it meant something, now it is just jargon.

Comment: "In depth" doesn't seem overused to me. You could use that or "intensive study," although that's not just one word.

Answer (score 8):

What first came to mind was:

> [**delve**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/delve): to carry on intensive and thorough research for data, information, or the like; investigate:
>   *to delve into the issue of prison reform.*

Usually used with *into*, as in the example above.

Source: [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Comment: Hey there codebreaker, please note that direct quotations require source citation(s). Please credit *Dictionary.com*, so I can up-vote this fine suggestion.

Comment: @LittleEva Fixed.  So it's not enough to just have a link?

Comment: codebreaker, my experience with this is that EL&U strongly urges us to explicitly credit all direct quotations of others' material, on pain of deletion. Your edit now has two links to essentially the same location, all that is required is to leave the 'delve' link in place, use a plain text citation for the quotation, e.g., **(Dictionary.com)**, anywhere you deem appropriate in the body of your post. Thank you, and +1.

Comment: How's that for a response - now you're the leader of the pack!

Comment: @LittleEva Okay, that makes sense, I see how other people are doing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, ***[investigation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/investigation)*** is the word that you are looking for.

> A formal inquiry or systematic study

(OED)

Answer (score 4):

This was called a [***deep dive***](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/deep-dive) where I used to work:

> an in-depth exploration

It's mostly used in the noun sense in business. "Tsk. We'll have to perform a deep-dive on this" or "let's do a deep dive on this tomorrow."  It can mean exhaustively examining every facet of an issue.

It's a good noun to use in conjunction with the verb *delve* suggested earlier.  A noun is needed in the business sense because a "deep dive" begins to take on a certain scheduled ominousness in the noun sense like *exam, test, audit* and *review*.

Comment: What an apt metaphor! It does indeed _take on a certain scheduled ominousness in the noun sense_. I have worked in organisations where taking a _**deep dive**_ (not that I would have thought to call it that) was dangerous, because you never knew what you might encounter in the dark and murky depths and if you would return to the surface unscathed.

Comment: _Deep dive_ was a completely new expression to me before I read this answer and yet just today Adobe Systems emailed me with the subject: **_Get a deep-dive into creative skills._**

So what's with that hyphen? I would hyphenate it only as a compound adjective, for example: _It's not looking good. I think we've got another **deep-dive situation** in the making._

Answer (score 3):

I might consider dividing out those studies which only took a couple of weeks and those that you spent a few months on and labeling them differently. For the studies that were only a few weeks, maybe something along the lines of "background research," "examination," or "inquiry." For those projects which you spent several months on, you might want something that packs a little more punch, like "comprehensive analysis." Or stick them all together: "During the past several years I engaged in a range of inquires on a variety of subjects, including background research on x, a through examination of y, as well as a comprehensive analysis of z." It's an easy way to denote which projects you have spent more time on and which projects you were less engaged in.

Answer (score 2):

OP could describe these intensive, concentrated studies as, *focused research*.

---

> [**focused**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/focused) *adjective*: giving a lot of attention to one particular thing: the need for more *focused research* (Cambridge Dictionaries *online*)

---

> [**research**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/research)
>
> **1**. careful or diligent search
>
> **2**. studious inquiry or examination; especially: investigation or experimentation aimed at the discovery and interpretation of facts, revision of accepted theories or laws in the light of new facts, or practical application of such new or revised theories or laws
>
> **3**. the collecting of information about a particular subject; (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Answer (score 2):

Originally, a *perusal* would have been exactly this, from the verb *peruse* which meant

> to examine or read (something) in a very careful way

but has come to mean

> to look at or read (something) in an informal or relaxed way

which is the very opposite. (Both definitions from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse).)

To a sufficiently pedantic crowd, however, *perusal* might remain an option for expressing this. Especially since the noun form *perusal* does not see the casual use that *peruse* does, the fact that you are using that form may be a cue to the right audience that you are using the word “correctly.”

Unfortunately, the risk of being interpreted as meaning the exact opposite of what you intend probably eliminates this from consideration.

Comment: +1 KRyan, as *EL&U* registers in the *red zone* on *pedant-o-meters*!

Comment: No way.  Next you'll be telling me that *dilettante* means someone who assiduously applies themselves.

Comment: @stevesliva *General* originally meant “in all cases, with no exceptions,” and has completely switched meaning to “in most cases, but with frequent or expected exceptions.”

Comment: Oh, I love trivia, and this is that!  "No way" was *positive* incredulity.

Answer (score 1):

A verb for this might be to [*pore over*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/232466/77065):

> To examine something closely; in great detail. It can also refer to meditating over something, and to be fully absorbed in a subject.

It is, as the answer in the link says, usually associated with "academics who are passionate about their fields, and students who study obsessively before an important exam."

Comment: No, I don't think this is right. *Pore over* is used to mean examining a specific text or book. It isn't really used to mean analysing a topic.

Comment: Agree with @Charon.  If you can't use *scrutinize*, you probably don't want to use *pore over.*

Answer (score 1):

Contemplation or meditation, as in "he meditated on the question for many days".
A "brown study" is a moody attitude, whether sad or angry.

Answer (score 1):

An in-depth study of something would properly be called a ***[survey](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survey)***:

> to view or consider comprehensively
>
> *According to a New York Times report, the DOJ is **surveying** claims that the ticketing company is forcing venues to use its subsidiary, Ticketmaster, as vendor for high-profile events.*
>
> — [Patrick Shanley, The Hollywood Reporter, "Live Nation’s Ruthless Business Practices Reportedly Probed by Justice Department," 1 Apr. 2018](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/department-justice-looking-live-nation-business-practices-ny-times-reports-1098850)

[MW]

Simply typing the phrase “a survey of” into Google Scholar yields many such of [such kinds of surveys](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=a%20survey%20of&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).

Answer (score 0):

Many words come to mind while describing your act.

1. Thorough insight.
2. Recursive study. (Recursive insight).
3. Profound research. (abstract research)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a term (noun) to describe this or a verb to describe the act of doing the deep study on a particular topic

How about **immersion**?

From WordNet 3.0:

> n 3. complete attention; intense mental effort

Colloquially, I've also heard **deep dive** used, in the context of troubleshooting, and especially in  root cause analysis, to refer to an intensive, often protracted investigation or study.

[Here's a source](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/deep-dive) defining **deep dive** as:

> an in-depth exploration.

Both terms are analogous to being deeply submerged in water, and possibly alluding to the [mammalian diving reflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammalian_diving_reflex).

> The mammalian diving reflex is a reflex in mammals which optimizes respiration to allow staying underwater for extended periods of time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**blow-by-blow**

By [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blow-by-blow) : A blow-by-blow description contains every detail and action of an event

**E.g.**

> However, we do not purport to offer in this book a detailed, **blow by blow** study of how each organisation set about inventing and implementing its system of PIs. 
>   [ref: https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1134813651]

Answer (score 0):

The verb **to scrutinize** captures the meaning well.

`scrutinize : to examine in detail with careful or critical attention.`

Answer (score 0):

**Odyssey**

I suggest ‘odyssey’ as it means a *journey* through something that is ‘epic’ - monsters are encountered and beheaded, Sirens beguile and are avoided and dragons are slain.

Studying and learning are a personal journey through which you encounter yourself, confront misunderstandings, judgements and inner conflicts, on your quest for your personal ‘truth’.

Odyssey derives from the adventures of Odysseus - his epic spiritual journey.

You can also say ‘spiritual odyssey’, ‘emotional odyssey’, ‘linguistic odyssey’ or ‘odyssey of self-discovery’, etc.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odyssey

Answer (score -3):

The could be termed an **exposition**, especially if it is written.

From WordNet 3.0:

> exposition
>
> n 1: a systematic interpretation or explanation (usually written) of a specific topic ...
>
> 3: an account that sets forth the meaning or intent of a writing or discourse ...

Comment: I don't think this really fits